# DynamoDB or DynamoDB2: can I determine if someone is using a table I just got?

Tags: synchronization, amazon-dynamodb

Suppose I got a Dynamo table (I'll assume DynamoDB below):

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_dynamodb(aws_access_key_id=<MYID>,aws_secret_access_key=<MYKEY>)
table = conn.get_table('someTable')
```

Is there any way to **reliably** determine whether or not there is another process out there in the world that is currently writing into this table?

As far as I understand, checking `table.status` for `UPDATING` or `DELETING` won't help since I will get `ACTIVE` whether or not someone is writing into the table or not, as long as noone is modifying table's throughput or deleting the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. DynamoDB doesnt support transactions or locking etc. 
You need to model your data and application code in such a way, that even if another process is writing/reading, it doesnt impact your data.

Checking table status doesnt help - Once a table is created, the most of the time it is ACTIVE. This is only for creation or updation of tables (and not for writing items)

Dynamo provides some features like the following to help in such data modeling:

1. Conditional Update (You can tell the write should happen only if the
   value of an attribute is say X).
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItemsConditionalUpdate
2. Atomic Counters (say you want to do an increment by 1, without somebody intercepting between your read and then the subsequent write): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters

Hope this helps !